# Get email Id of a user using Login name in Dot net CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom, user

I need to get the email id of a user using Dot net CSOM.

All I have is his Login name "`i:0#.w|fpl\mxj0`"

Please advice..

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve all user profile properties for a particular user using .NET CSOM.
All you need is the Server URL and username.

Read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163182.aspx#Anchor_3)